# Diffraction and interference

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction

I read about diffraction and interference and I did not understand if the points for maximum or first maximum and so on, for diffraction and interference are the same.

Answer (score 0):

For two-slit interference, the intensity profile given by
$$I(\theta)=4I_0\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi a\sin\theta}{\lambda}\right)$$
The maximum given by:
$$a\sin\theta=m\lambda$$

While for Diffraction,
$$I(\theta)=I(0)\left(\frac{\sin\beta}{\beta}\right)^2,\ \ \ \ \ \beta=\frac{\pi b\sin\theta}{\lambda}$$
The position of maxima given by
$$\tan\beta=\beta$$

The central maxima matches but others do not.

Comment: thanks! But if we have a gitter of, say 200 gaps/mm and For light with the wavelength $λ_1 = 550$ nm, the first diffraction maximum is registered at an angle $θ_1 = 30$ At what angle  will the first diffraction maximum be observed for $λ_2 = 650nm$?

I used the formula $d sin(\theta)=m \lambda_1$, where $d$ is $\frac{1}{1000}$, But I dont know how to solve for the angle :/

Comment: $d=\frac{1}{200}$ *****

Comment: Oh.. I solved it.. I did an easy mistake!